# Remastering issues with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, grub2, preseed

I am trying to create my own distro using Ubuntu 18.04 - I am using Preseed methods and have created my own preseed file and appended just like below. And created my ISO image. However, installer still prompting me to choose the options.

Any clue why?

```
$ more boot/grub/grub.cfg

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
        set gfxmode=auto
        insmod efi_gop
        insmod efi_uga
        insmod gfxterm
        terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Install Trap v1.2" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/trap.seed debian-installer/locale=en_US  console-setup/layoutcode=us  boot=casper quiet  ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

```
$ more isolinux/txt.cfg

default trap
label trap
  menu label ^Install Trap 1.2
  menu default
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed/trap.seed debian-installer/locale=en_US console-setup/layoutcode=us boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd ramdisk_size=16384 root=/
dev/ram rw quiet  ---
```

Am I missing anything? Any other file that I need to modify to achieve? Is there any good tutorial or article available for the complete remastering of Ubuntu 18.04 to create my own distro to ship my application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed to append `automatic-ubiquity`. At least that's what I did with Xubuntu 18.